# How to make a webpage with links to launch installed apps on android?

Tags: android, html, launcher, android-launcher, app-launcher

I want to limit which apps unauthorized users use on my phone... I want to create a simple webpage which will contain a list links to only the android apps that I want...

```
<html>
    <body>
        <a href="../link/to/app">Calculator</a>
        <a href="../link/to/app">Chrome</a>
        <a href="../link/to/app">Wikipedia</a>
        <a href="../link/to/app">WordWeb</a>
        <a href="../link/to/app">GoogleEarth</a>
        <a href="../link/to/app">GoogleMaps</a>
        <a href="../link/to/app">YouTube</a>
    </body>
</html>
```

I don't want to use some app locker or minimalist launcher. I'll remove all apps from the app drawer and just pin this webpage to the homescreen. When the icon is clicked, webpage opens in a browser, user clicks on links to open the app, the app launches...

I don't want this to work globally... Just a local webpage... (location of app installation changes on different phones).

How can I find the href to locally installed apps?

Comment: have you tried passing the package name as URL?
For example: `com.google.android.youtube` for YouTube

Comment: Just using <a href="com.google.android.youtube">YouTube</a> gives ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND. As the webpage isn't in the location of the app...

Comment: If you are using webview, you need to handle links externally. You need to check if app is available. If available, then open using intent.

Comment: I know to app is installed. But I don't know where neither do I how to use intents in href...?

Answer (score 3):

Try this solution :

```
<a href="
intent:
  //8xn9iq3lG_w/
  #Intent;
    scheme=vnd.youtube;
    package=com.google.android.youtube
    S.browser_fallback_url=market://details?id=com.google.android.youtube;
end;
">youtube or market</a>
```

Maybe you need to remove spaces in *href attribut*:

```
<a href="intent://8xn9iq3lG_w/#Intent;scheme=vnd.youtube;package=com.google.android.youtube;S.browser_fallback_url=market://details?id=com.google.android.youtube;end;">youtube or market</a>
```

**UPDATE 1 :**

`scheme` -> you need to search

`package` -> you can find by openning playstore in browser

`S.browser_fallback_url` -> only package name needs to be changed(same as `package`).

Comment: Works for youtube. <a href="intent://8xn9iq3lG_w/#Intent;scheme=vnd.youtube;package=org.videolan.vlc;S.browser_fallback_url=market://details?id=com.google.android.youtube;end;">VLC</a> doesn't work...

Comment: you need to search `scheme`, `package` and `S.browser_fallback_url` for different apps you want to use. these 3 parameters will be changed for each app.

Comment: Here's the manifest file for VLC https://pastebin.com/raw/EGpT1zzc I made this link 
<a href="intent:/#Intent;scheme=vlclauncher;package=org.videolan.vlc";>VLC</a> but it doesn't work.